# Spinner in Android with navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-listview, spinner, android-spinner

How do I add the spinner here? actually this is a project with navigation drawer.

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{
public ListViewFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
}
```

where should i add it?

Comment: How about in your layout.xml?

Comment: @giant00 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/osversions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{
public ListViewFragment(){}
Spinner mspinner; //declare spinner globally
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

mspinner        = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("list 1");
list.add("list 2");
list.add("list 3");
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mspinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

//do something when particular item is selected from spinner

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
}
```

Comment: How do i set the adapter?